# Как изменить данные в SqLite3?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

Пытаюсь внести данные в таблицу, но дает ошибку `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: test.user_id`, что делать?

Код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram import md
import sqlite3
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
conn = sqlite3.connect('DataBase.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()


def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str, user_nick: str):
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, user_nick) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, user_nick))
   conn.commit()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_text_messages(message: types.Message):
   if "+ник" in message.text:
       await message.reply('Привет! Ваш ник добавлено в базу данных!')
       args= message.text.split()
       us_id = message.from_user.id
       us_name = message.from_user.first_name
       us_sname = message.from_user.last_name
       username = message.from_user.username

       db_table_val(user_id=us_id, user_name=us_name, user_surname=us_sname, username=username, user_nick=args[2])


   elif message.text == "мой ник":
       cur = conn.cursor()
       cur.execute('SELECT user_nick FROM test WHERE user_id = ?', (message.from_user.id,))
       one_result = cur.fetchone()
       await message.reply(*one_result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На поле user_id наложено ограничение (оно должно быть уникальным для каждой строки).
Ошибка утверждает о том, что данное ограничение запросы пытается нарушить, т.е. добавить пользователя с именем, которое уже есть в таблице.
Перед тем, как делать INSERT, нужно проверять - нет ли там уже пользователя с таким ником..